# OverflowError: int too large to convert to float

Tags: python

```
def tailor(x):
    s = 0
    l = 3 * x
    for n in range(1, 1025):
        term = ((-1)**(n-1))*((1+2**n)*x**n)/n
        if abs(term) < 0.000001:
            break
        if abs(term) > l:
            exit(2)
        s += term
    return s
x = 0.5
print(tailor(x), math.log(1+3*x+2*x**2))
```

Код вычисляет значение функции ln(1+3x+2x^2) путем сложения членов заданного ее ряда S с точностью 10^(-6). Выдает ошибку OverflowError: int too large to convert to float, полагаю связанно с ограничениями типов, можно ли как то решить проблему?

[image: ряд]

Comment: Возьмите половину диапазона 512

Comment: Не очень вникал в суть вычислений но попробуйте так `x = Decimal(0.5)`

Comment: Можно использовать numpy.float128

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь вычислить член ряда напрямую деля гигантские числа. Вместо этого следующий член может быть вычислен из предыдущего. При этом больших значений не возникает. Дополнительно я убрал ограничение на число итераций и вывел это число на печать:

```
def tailor(x):
    t1 = -1
    t2 = -1
    s = 0
    n = 1
    while True:
        t1 *= -x
        t2 *= -2 * x
        term = (t1 + t2) / n
        if abs(term) < 0.000001:
            return s, n
        assert abs(term) <= 3 * x, f'limit! {term} > 3 * {x}'
        s += term
        n += 1


for i in range(11):
    x = i / 20
    y, n = tailor(x)
    y2 = math.log(1 + 3 * x + 2 * x ** 2)
    print(f'{x:.2f}', f'{y:.10f}', f'{y2:.10f}', n)
```

> ```
> $ python tailor.py
> 0.00 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 1
> 0.05 0.1441005000 0.1441003440 6
> 0.10 0.2776320095 0.2776317366 8
> 0.15 0.4021266715 0.4021262068 10
> 0.20 0.5187934168 0.5187937934 13
> 0.25 0.6286093082 0.6286086594 16
> 0.30 0.7323682739 0.7323678937 22
> 0.35 0.8307332915 0.8307328435 30
> 0.40 0.9242583585 0.9242589015 45
> 0.45 1.0134169394 1.0134174426 89
> 0.50 1.0986117887 1.0986122887 1000001
> ```

**P.S.** Ряд знакопеременный. Его вычисление можно ускорить. Но это совсем другая история.